# Purchased music from Google Play - they are nowhere to be found

Tags: google-play-store, music, google-play-music

I purchased 3 x albums 4 days ago using Play Store. It advised that the purchase was successful and the money was debited from my account - but it never actually said it was downloading anything. These albums are not in my Play Music...and if I go back to Play Store it says that they have been purchased - when I click on the album i get the option to listen. When I press listen it opens up in a web page "google play music" and has the option to Buy or Listen. I press listen - the screen refreshes. Absolutely nothing happens. How do I get these albums into my Play Music?? thank you

Answer (score 0):

They will be in Google's [Play Music](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.music) app. You can listen or download them from that app.